# Add result from for loop rasterstats zonal_stats to gpd shapefile attributes as new columns

Tags: python, geopandas, for-loop, rasterstats

I am trying to use a for loop which would produce the zonal statistics of multiple rasters at shapefile points and then add each raster stat to the shapefile.

I've gotten it to add a column, but I don't know how to make the column change the name from 'max' to what the raster is or an abbreviation of it so it doesn't add the rest of the zonal_stats output.

```
import rasterstats as rs
from raster2xyz.raster2xyz import Raster2xyz
import os, fnmatch

inputFolder = "C:/585L/PROJECT/precip/clipped_2016/"
fire_ign = gpd.read_file("C:/585L/PROJECT/fire_points/fire_pts_clip2016_2021.shp")
fire_ign_slim = fire_ign[['FIRE_YEAR', 'MTBS_FIRE_', 'DISCOVERY_', 'FIRE_SIZE', 'LATITUDE', 'LONGITUDE', 'FIPS_NAME', 'geometry']]

def findRasters (path, filter):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, filter):
        for file in fnmatch.filter(files, filter):
            yield os.path.join (root, file)

            
for raster in findRasters (inputFolder, '*.bil'):
    stats = rs.zonal_stats(fire_ign_slim,
                      raster, 
                      stats = "max")
    statsdf = pd.DataFrame(stats)
    df_redux = pd.concat([statsdf, fire_ign_slim], axis = 1)
```

Results in:

```
max     FIRE_YEAR   MTBS_FIRE_  DISCOVERY_  FIRE_SIZE   LATITUDE    LONGITUDE   FIPS_NAME   geometry
616.276001  2016    CLARK   8/4/2016    2819.0  37.798889   -118.922500     Mono County     POINT (-118.92249 37.79888)
```

The clipped_2016 folder has 13, one for each month of the year and an annual, rasters in it though, and I would like to see the max of all 13 rasters with an appropriate name.

So it might read something like:

```
FIRE_YEAR   MTBS_FIRE_  DISCOVERY_  FIRE_SIZE   LATITUDE    LONGITUDE   FIPS_NAME   geometry    ppt_201601  ppt_201602  ppt_201603  ppt_201604
2016    CLARK   8/4/2016    2819.0  37.798889   -118.922500     Mono County     POINT (-118.92249 37.79888)     some number from raster     some number from raster     some number from raster     some number from raster
```

But I am stuck on figuring out how to take each zonal stat from each point from each raster and putting those numbers into a df with unique column named from the raster it was taken from.

And this is how my clipped_2016 folder looks if it is helpful:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os.path` (`basename` and `splitext`) to get the raster name without path and extension and just add the `max` column to the dataframe with a new name: e.g.

```
import os.path

etc...

for raster in findRasters (inputFolder, '*.bil'):
    stats = rs.zonal_stats(fire_ign_slim,
                      raster, 
                      stats = "max")
    raster_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(raster))[0]
    statsdf = pd.DataFrame(stats)
    fire_ign_slim[f"max_{raster_name}"] = statsdf["max"]
```

Or if you prefer `concat`, you can [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html) the `max` column:

```
for raster in findRasters (inputFolder, '*.bil'):
    stats = rs.zonal_stats(fire_ign_slim,
                      raster, 
                      stats = "max")
    raster_name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(raster))[0]
    statsdf = pd.DataFrame(data={'max': [1, 2, 3]}).rename(columns={"max": f"max_{raster_name}"})
    fire_ign_slim = pd.concat([fire_ign_slim, statsdf], axis=1)
```

Note that `fire_ign_slim` is the output from `concat`, not `df_redux` otherwise you are continually adding only one column.

Comment: Thank you, this works for renaming the column, but it still only adds the first raster in the folder to the dataframe when using 'df_redux = pd.concat([statsdf, fire_ign_slim], axis = 1)'. I was hoping each raster's zonal stats would be added to the dataframe but maybe I am looping the concat wrong, I don't know

Comment: @sarakota you only get one column added as you `concat` `statsdf` to `fire_ign_slim` and output to `df_redux` instead of `fire_ign_slim`

Comment: Thank you very much, this solved my question, and thank you for explaining what I did wrong. That makes it easier for me to understand